# How To Save Value With Format Currency Textbox ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I use this code for display currency format in the Edit View. (The salary datatype is decimal)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Salary, new { dir = "rtl", @Value = string.Format("{0:C}", Model.Salary) })
```

But when i trying to save my changes, why the salary property always contains null? How to save the value with format currency in a textbox?

Comment: perhaps, because the value attribute is null. Can you test it without "@Value = ..."?

Comment: the value attribute isn't null. If "@Value" removed, it means the value in textbox isn't formatted as currency

Comment: you can use as `@Html.TextBox("Salary",String.Format("{0:#,###}", m=>m.Salary));`

Comment: I don't agree with you, because "@Value" set the value of textbox, and you may write it only as "@Value = Model.DateModified.ToString("{0:c}")". In you code you set the value ass null